# managed metadata field shows id in sharepoint 2010 designer email

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, managed-metadata

When I try to log SharePoint Managed metadata column in my SharePoint 2010 Designer workflow, it logs as 'text|someid'

**Example:'Materials|8b39e69e-6776-4b7a-b1ea-a51556d94c65'**.

I want to get rid of the id part. I tried to use the substrings action, but couldn't achieve. I am using designer 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the solution mentioned in this [post](http://sympmarc.com/2012/11/09/displaying-managed-metadata-column-values-in-an-email-sent-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/) and it worked.

1. Start with your managed metadata column (Column1Name)
2. Create a 2nd column (Column2Name) in the list of type string
3. Create a workflow that fires on create and/or on modify (depending on your needs) that copies the value from Column1Name into Column2Name.
4. Create a 3rd calculated column (Column3Name) on the list. The formula for that column should be =LEFT([Column2Name],FIND(“|”,[Column2Name])-1) The calculation finds the pipe character and trims the value to a clean text value.
5. Any emails where you need to display the value of Column1Name should use the value of Column3Name instead to send the plain text